# How to show specific attribute under product name on Woocommerce Shop Page

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I've been struggling to find information about how to achieve this:

I want for one specific attribute (Brand), to be visible and present under the product name on the Shop Page.

How can I achieve this?
Theme: Zakra

Thanks in advance.
Alex.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code display the attribute below the product title on the shop page.

I guess the taxonomy name for the brand should be (pa_brand). If the name is different then replace the taxonomy name of BRAND and replace(pa_brand) it in the below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_brand_attribute', 5 );
function display_brand_attribute() {
    global $product;

        $taxonomy = 'pa_brand';
        echo '<span class="attribute-brand">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: Glad that I could help. Do upvote and accept the answer.